# How to fix when there is bubble after putting tempered glass and why is this happening?

Tags: phone

I am using Iphone SE. When I put the tempered glass there generated bubble in the corner.  I tried to fix it but it does not work & I have changed my tempered glass twice but still the bubble gets generated. Why is this happening & how do I fix this?

Comment: A picture might help, and an explanation of what "put the tempered glass" means... as an overlay?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik You've never heard of tempered glass screen protectors?

Comment: Or is it a screen replacement?

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the corner it is probably due to **micro dust**, you need to use a **micro fiber tissue** in order to remove them. Sometime when you buy a screen protector there is a **sticker** sent with it that helps to get those micro dust stuck on the sticker. Also doing this in an **humid environment** such as a bathroom seems to help .
source : [Bathroom steam](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/install-screen-protector-in-bathroom-steam-shower.1151517/%22Bathroom%20steam%20shower%22)

Answer (score 0):

If the bubble is in the middle of the glass (it's not touching any sides), then it could be a piece of dust.  Sometimes you can see them, sometimes you can't.  What you can do is get a piece of tape (masking tape works best), lift up the corner closest to the bubble, then slide the tape in between the glass and the phone. Press down on it, then lift the corner up again and slide the tape out.  Most of the time, the dust is stuck on the screen protector so try with the sticky side up first.  If it doesn't work, flip the masking tape and try with the sticky side down.  Do not take the screen protector off all the way or you will likely get more dust inside.

When you let the corner down, slightly press the protector from the inside and slide your finger towards the outside to slide the air out.  With practice, you should be able to get it nearly perfect.